# How can implement search bar in android?

Tags: android

I am working in android. i am trying to display name of university using listView.

my list view is looking like this.
[image]

Now i want to add a search bar on the top of this list view. if i press **A** in search bar then this list view should display all the name of university start with **A**, if i press some other character then according university name must be displayed.

Please tell me how can implement this. Is any way to make search bar in android. I have seen in iPhone, it works very efficiently in iPhone. Please help me how can make this search bar ?

Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may be the long way. but this is just an idea..

I think you have to create a layout xml file with one `EditText` and `ListView`.  Inside activity you have to listen for textChange in `EditText` and then probably you have to filter your `ListAdapter`based on the text entered by the user and bind it with `ListView`.

See the complete example here : http://www.androidpeople.com/android-listview-searchbox-sort-items

Comment: Thank you all for your help. THis is also a very good tutorial:-  http://android-helper.blogspot.com/2011/03/android-search-in-listview-example.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`setTextFilterEnabled(true)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setTextFilterEnabled%28boolean%29http://) on your list view.

Answer (score 1):

I think this may help you to get an idea. http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-autocomplete.html